# SQL combine query using subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

Hello I have two queries like this

```
select COUNT(*)as Num_Occ, trial 
into ##temp_occ
from [E1].[dbo].[EVENT_SIM]
where MODELING_ID=1
group by trial,MODELING_ID
order by TRIAL

select Num_Occ, count(*)as Num_Trials
from ##temp_occ 
group by Num_Occ ORDER BY Num_Occ
```

I do not wish to create temporary table to do this all the time, so I combine the two using subquery. However my code returns errors saying invalid names Num_Occ.

```
  select Num_Occ, count(*)as Num_Trials
from [E1].[dbo].[EVENT_SIM]
where NUM_Occ in (select COUNT(*)as Num_Occ 
from [E1].[dbo].[EVENT_SIM]
where MODELING_ID=1)
```

Could you please help me understand where I should change? Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be better if you could post the table schema, and explain a little more on the objective and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to combine them:

```
select Num_Occ, count(*) as Num_Trials
from (select COUNT(*) as Num_Occ, trial 
      from [E1].[dbo].[EVENT_SIM]
      where MODELING_ID = 1
      group by trial, MODELING_ID
     ) t
group by Num_Occ
ORDER BY Num_Occ;
```

You want to put the subquery in the `from` clause not the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

two queries can be combined to :

```
select Num_Occ, count(*)as Num_Trials
from (

select COUNT(*)as Num_Occ, trial 
from [E1].[dbo].[EVENT_SIM]
where MODELING_ID=1
group by trial,MODELING_ID


) as temptable 
group by Num_Occ ORDER BY Num_Occ
```

But subqueries can cause non-optimal query plans.